# Drawing pdf in Cocoa with antialias

Tags: objective-c, image, cocoa, pdf

I am developing an application which requires converting pdf to image. The problem I am facing is in some pdfs there is some white lines.

This is the code i use for converting pdf to image.

```
NSPDFImageRep* pdfRep = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithContentsOfFile:path];
[pdfRep setCurrentPage:page];

NSBitmapImageRep* bmRep;

NSRect pdfBounds=[pdfRep bounds];

NSRect target=[NSBitmapImageRep scalingSizeFittingIn:pdfBounds.size targetSize:size];

bmRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                                pixelsWide:size.width
                                                pixelsHigh:size.height
                                             bitsPerSample:8
                                           samplesPerPixel:4
                                                  hasAlpha:YES
                                                  isPlanar:NO
                                            colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                               bytesPerRow:0
                                              bitsPerPixel:0];

NSGraphicsContext* context = [NSGraphicsContext
                              graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:bmRep];

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:context];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setShouldAntialias:NO];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setColorRenderingIntent:NSColorRenderingIntentPerceptual];

// draw the PDF rep into the bitmap rep.
[pdfRep drawInRect:target];

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
```

If I set ShouldAntialias to NO than the image is [image: Image with antialise set to NO]

And this is the image with ShouldAntialias set to YES [image: Image with antialise set to YES]

The question is how can I get rid of the white stripes and keep the image smooth?
Thanks.

Comment: Which OS version is this?